# Issue importing DIO library in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, dio

I found an error importing package from the 'DIO' library and it's the following:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: from Android Studio. please see the error in the attached screenshot.

I want to get rid of [this red marked error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUMFW.png).

I followed the guidelines described in [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)
and here is the `pub spec` details:

```
#REMOTE DATA   dio: ^4.0.0
```

and did pub get

I tried dio: ^5.0.0 also but result is the same.

Comment: try to run `flutter pub get` after library added

Comment: go to the `pubspec.yaml`, click on `Pub Get` look at the above. Then `restart` your `Android Studio`.

Answer (score 0):

May be because the Dio package is now obsolete.
I recomend you choose another package.

- [Message of Wendux, the creator of Dio package](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/1644)
- [DIO Github](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/1607)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the result for `flutter pub get` here? It seems the pub get is failing.

Please run the following commands before `flutter pub get`:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `rm pubspec.lock`
3. `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/` if you're on Mac